# github wouldn't remove a high volume directory

Tags: github

I have cloned a repository that has `3.8G` of data. (Well, bordering stupidity but I mistakenly uploaded an image dataset.) Now, I would like to remove it but `git rm -r` wouldn't remove it. I need this directory to be removed from local as well as remote `master` repository. The command has been running for well over `2 days` now. I believe it is stuck. Please I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me a way out of this situation. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Simply removing the files from your local repository, or preventing them from being `git push`ed?

Comment: I'm remove the directory `x` and the would like to commit it, and push the changes. I would like `x` to be removed completely from everywhere, remote(web) & local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1: Deleting it from your local repository

You want to delete the images from your local repository.

#### Solution:

On the command line, do a `rm -rf x`, where `x` is the directory that contains the images, `-r` is the recursive flag used to delete directories and subdirectories contained within, and `-f` is the force flag to delete protected files.

---

### Problem 2: Preventing it from being committed

You don't want the images to be pushed to the codebase/online repository.

#### Solution:

If you already deleted the files from your local repository, you can check that the directory was removed by running a `git status` command. The deleted directory should be printed in red font. All you need to do is `git rm x` to confirm that the directory is to be deleted and be removed from the codebase/online repository. Then, of course, run a `git commit` and then a `git push <origin> <master>`.

---

### Alternative:

Although you said you wanted to delete the image set, next time if you want to keep it locally but prevent it from being pushed to the codebase/online repository, create a `.gitignore` file and specify the directory or file type you *don't* want pushed. A tutorial on `.gitignore` files can be found [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore).

Comment: Thanks. but, right now `x` directory is already on remote. I need to remove it, from local as well as from `master` i.e. online. I can do it 2 ways, if I understand correctly, I can use `rm -rf`(unix command) and then do a git commit and push. Second option is to use `git rm -r`.

Problem is if I use the first option, i.e. use `rm -rf` unix command, git commit gets successfully completed, but git push gets stuck, for hours stay on `0%`.If I use second option,i.e `git rm -r`, to remove directory `x`, the command gets stuck again. I have been waiting for it to come back for a day and a half.

Comment: Alternative advice is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Ahsan In regards to the 2 solutions I provided, you'll have to do both in order for achieve your desired result: solution 1, then solution 2. Solution 1 has nothing to do with git--it's just a unix command. To commit and push the changes, sometimes I notice that I have to press "enter", otherwise the changes don't show. Make sure you're being prompted to enter your git credentials and whatnot.